# How to call html button onclick javascript function with aspx parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, onclick

I need to pass parameters from repeater to javascript function. But I can't do it like this:

```
     onclick="myFunction(<%# ((myObject)Container.DataItem).myValue) %>)"
```

It says syntax error.

I need to call `myFunction(myValue)` javascript function. 
And the `myValue` have to come from

```
     <%# ((myObject)Container.DataItem).myValue) %>
```

What is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: onclick="myFunction('<%# ((myObject)Container.DataItem).myValue) %>')"

Comment: No it is not working in my ascx file. 
"Unterminated string constant Expected ')'"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write all of it in the markup (and not in rowdatabound or somewhere in code behind) you can use this syntax:

```
onclick = '<%# "myFunction(" + Container.DataItemIndex + ")" %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add a couple of quotes:

`onclick="myFunction("<%# ((myObject)Container.DataItem).myValue %>")"`

This should work with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This does not work also. It says Unterminated string constant

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you pass string

```
onclick='<%# string.Format("myFunction(\"{0}\")",((myObject)Container.DataItem).myValue)%>'
```

otherwise use following...

```
onclick='<%# string.Format("myFunction({0})",((myObject)Container.DataItem).myValue)%>'
```

Comment: I thought that too, but with the first option I ended up with ysod saying parse error. But yes, i'm passing string.

Comment: Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Comment: ok, i need full tag, not just onclick attribute. because i wanted to know what you are using linkbutton or button or input (runat=server)?

Answer (score 0):

**Try adding the onclick from Server Side,**

```
Control.Attributes.Add("onclick",((myObject)Container.DataItem).myValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this.Modify this according to your requirement.

```
protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {

var jsFunction = String.Format("Javascriptfunctionname('{0}','{1}');", parameter1, parameter2);
Gridcontrol.Attributes.Add("onclick", jsFunction);

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code.

```
onclick="javascript:myFunction("<%=((myObject)Container.DataItem).myValue) %>")";
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `=` instead of `#`

`onclick = "myFunction(<%= ( (myObject)Container.DataItem).myValue ) %>)"`

Comment: are you sure Container accessible in <%= %>?